# 500 internal error while uploading a wesbite on shared hosting server

Tags: php, laravel

i made a website in laravel framework which was running fine on local server so then i started uploading it on server.firstly i made a zip file of all the files except public file,and uploaded it inside the folder called 'laravel' that i made inside the home directory in my cpanel and extracted the contents.after that i made a zip of public and uploaded the zip inside public_html folder and unzipped it.then i edited the index.php to/../bootstrap/ to /../laravel/bootstrap at the two places and saved it..after that i dumped the databse and did it sucessfully made changes in.env file.the problem is that now there is 500 internal server error

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was                   unable to complete your request.

 Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@tncpscouriers.com       to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

 More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

 Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

initially there was a one page static website,so i thought of changing te index .php to bring it back again but it still does not work.i am clueless now,kindly help today is my deadline to handover the project to client 
my .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Go thorough https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.3xkn2vgka

Comment: Check the server error logs and any logs in `/storage/logs`, it will give you a reason why you're getting the 500 error. A 500 error itself is way too broad to troubleshoot.

Comment: in my cpanel i went to errors in the matrix header.there were listing of errors`5:08.076146 2017] [:error] [pid 12349] [client 49.202.144.203:46977] SoftException in Application.cpp:651: Directory "/home/tncpscouriers/public_html" is writeable by group`

Comment: chmod `public_html` and sub-folders to `755`: `chmod -R 755 public_html`. Also, look for issues with `.htaccess`

Comment: I'd look more for Fatal Errors than SoftExceptions

Comment: where should i look for fatal errors???

Comment: i have chaged the setting of all the files inside public_html to 724 and it isn't writeable by anyone except used.

Comment: php version of the server is 5.5.38

Comment: i have read somehwere that laravel requires php version 5..6.4 or higher.

Comment: when i  change the php version of the domain it starts showing a blank page and in error messages it shows points to the php version.this happens for both 5.6 and 7.0 and when i again change it to 5.5  it starts showing internal 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the `.env` file in your folder

If not:

Generate your `.env`:

```
cp .env.example .env
```

Generate your key:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

After that, give the correct permissions to your laravel folder.

Enter in the laravel project

```
cd my_project_folder
```

Add the 644 permission to files and 755 to folders:

```
find ./ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find ./ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

If another error appears, try to update your composer

```
composer update
```

Comment: i was so messed up witht he permissions error that i by mistake changed it to 000 plz help me out noe,what can i do???

Comment: You removed your permissions, if it's only on your laravel folder, try to remove the entire folder, add again and add the permissions. If you do it in all your shared server, maybe you need to contact your host to reset your server.

Comment: i actually was doing it for public folder where it was showing the error,public_html is writable by group

Comment: joao mantovani actually i am using a gui there is no terminal provided.so i have no idea how to perform all these actions by command line.yes i have .env file and permission is a major headache for me here.because even if i change the permission to 622,644,755 there still is a error and moreover i think 644 is worng because this gives write permissions to group so 622 was correct according to me but still it was showing errror.